# Which Braintree API to use to pay multiple vendors at checkout

Tags: payment-gateway, braintree, marketplace

I am hoping to gain some "direction" about how to go about accomplishing this in Braintree :

I have a website where multiple vendors can sell their products. A customer can add to cart items from multiple vendors. If there are items from 2 vendors then, at checkout, the payment should get split into two recipients.
Which API can I use to accomplish this in Braintree? Most of the examples and resources I have read have only one recipient. 
Would you guys have some example code with multiple recipients?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Currently there is no way to do multi-seller cart checkouts with only one `Transaction.sale` call.

If you want to send payment to multiple merchants in Marketplace and do not mind having multiple transactions recorded, you can call `Transaction.sale` multiple times, substituting the `merchant_account_id` for the current merchant account id. Also note that you'll need a `payment_method_token` that you can find more info on [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby#payment_method_token)

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
  :merchant_account_id => "provider_sub_merchant_account",
  :amount => "10.00",
  :payment_method_token => "payment_method_token",
  :service_fee_amount => "your_service_fee"
)
```

For more info on Marketplace, please check out [the Braintree documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/marketplace/overview).